# Docker : "No such device" when using docker-compose to bind db file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using Docker to set up [Filebrowser](https://filebrowser.org).

Here is my docker-compose.yml :

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  filebrowser:
    container_name: filebrowser
    image: filebrowser/filebrowser:latest
    volumes:
      - /srv/mergerfs/storage:/srv
      - /srv/mergerfs/storage/services/filebrowser/filebrowser.db:/database.db
    ports:
      - 50005:80
    restart: unless-stopped
```

The container keeps restarting, and the logs show `No such device`.

If I remove the db bind mount, it works fine, but I cannot create any users in the Filebrowser UI (the users' config are stored in the db).

So I know the issue is coming from the db mount.

I can assure you the `filebrowser.db` file exists.

Why is it throwing that error ?